# Addon need to be upgraded from 2.7x to 2.8X Blender's version

Tags: blender, add-on

I have zero knowledge of programming. Please help me out. Thank you.
Here's the code.

```
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)
    bpy.types.INFO_MT_file_import.append(import_bob_menu)
    bpy.types.INFO_MT_file_export.append(export_bob_menu)
    bpy.types.INFO_MT_file_import.append(import_cob_menu)
    bpy.types.INFO_MT_file_export.append(export_cob_menu)
    bpy.types.INFO_MT_file_import.append(import_leveldefs)
    bpy.types.INFO_MT_file_export.append(export_leveldefs)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)
    bpy.types.INFO_MT_file_import.remove(import_bob_menu)
    bpy.types.INFO_MT_file_export.remove(export_bob_menu)
    bpy.types.INFO_MT_file_import.remove(import_cob_menu)
    bpy.types.INFO_MT_file_export.remove(export_cob_menu)
    bpy.types.INFO_MT_file_import.remove(import_leveldefs)
    bpy.types.INFO_MT_file_export.remove(export_leveldefs)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `bpy.utils.register_module` was removed in 2.80, you need to replace that with `bpy.utils.register_class` for each class that needs to be registered.

Repeating the example from [here](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.80/Python_API/Addons), adjust the classes list to include the classes in the addon. You will find a line like `class FooClass:` or `class FooClass(bpy.types.menu):` and you copy `FooClass` into the list. Then remove the `register_module` and `unregister_module` lines and replace them with the relevant three lines in the following example.

The naming of addon classes is also more strict so there is a chance that you will need to adjust some class names.

```
classes = (
    FooClass,
    BarClass,
    BazClass,
)

def register():
    from bpy.utils import register_class
    for cls in classes:
        register_class(cls)

def unregister():
    from bpy.utils import unregister_class
    for cls in reversed(classes):
        unregister_class(cls)
```

You will also find at the end of the [release notes page](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.80/Python_API/Addons) that class properties will also need to be changed -

2.7x:

```
class MyOperator(Operator):
    value = IntProperty()
```

2.8x:

```
class MyOperator(Operator):
    value: IntProperty()
```